# Your Ruby version is 2.6.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, ruby-2.5

Having trouble doing bundle.
My project is using 2.5.0 but every time i do `ruby -v` it gives me `ruby 2.6.0p0 (2018-12-25 revision 66547) [x86_64-darwin18]`

I am using rbenv and my `rbenv local` is `2.5.0` and `rbenv global` is `2.5.0`

Every time I do `Bundle` gives me an error `Your Ruby version is 2.6.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0`

I have tried `gem install bundler` but it doesn't solves the problem.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.0'
gem 'rails', '5.0'
```

and my .ruby-version is also `2.5.0`

Comment: Do you mentioned any ruby version in your gemfile? Something like `ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => '353'` in your Gemfile

Comment: just updated my question and yes i do mention ruby version in gemfile

Comment: Did you add "export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" in your .bashrc or etc?

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
gem install bundler

or

gem update bundler
```

which may fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using macOS and managed to solve this problem by using `rvm` first to install the desired ruby version (2.5.7 in my case).

Step-by-step:

- Install rvm from rvm.io - rvm version may be udpated with:

```
rvm get head
```

- Add rvm to your shell configuration, e.g. `~/.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin
source /Users/<YOUR_USER_NAME>/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

- Using rvm, install new Ruby version:

```
rvm install ruby-2.5.7
```

- Set the current/default version:

```
rvm use ruby-2.5.7 --default
```

- Modify your Gemfile to use the new Ruby version. E.g.:

```
ruby '2.5.7'
```

- Refresh the current Ruby version based on ./Gemfile by running:

```
rvm reload
```

- After installing a new version, from your project dir do:

```
gem install bundler
bundle update
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `Gemfile.lock` and try with proper version of ruby and run `bundle install`.

Comment: just deleted the Gemfile.lock and tried to run `bundle install` and got `Your Ruby version is 2.6.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.0`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using zsh, open your .zshrc by running

```
nano ~/.zshrc
```

then add these lines to the file

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

then run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried rbenv, and rvm and Nothing worked for me (I am using mac M1 chip. shell is Zsh).

But asdf worked eventually.

1. I installed asdf using `brew install asdf`
2. Added it to PATH with the following
   `cd ~` then `nano .zshrc`, type or paste `export PATH="$HOME/.asdf/shims:$PATH"` and save it to file by pressing `ctrl + X` and then press `Y` on your keyboard followed by `enter`
3. proceed to download ruby plugin for asdf using `asdf plugin add ruby`
4. then proceeded to download the ruby that is prompted in my error
   msg, 2.6.10 using `asdf install ruby 2.6.10`
5. set global ruby to 2.6.10 using `asdf global ruby 2.6.10` (change 'global' to 'local' if you only intend to set it locally)
6. Close the terminal and re-launch it
7. To check for the active ruby, I did `asdf current ruby` gave me 2.6.10
8. `ruby -v` also gave me 2.6.10. Please note that this is the first time it gave me that, so far, it had given me entirely something else even after 48hours of troubleshooting using rbenv and rvm

By now, the error message should be cleared. But if it persists (Which shouldn't). then create a `.tool-versions` file in your project root that contains the text of the ruby version we just installed eg `ruby 2.6.10`

I hope this helps someone on the other end of the internet
Good luck. PS, i uninstalled my rbenv

Answer (score -1):

If you are using VS Code, in the Gemfile you have a specified version of Ruby that you can change. I just ran into this issue and once I changed the version to my current version of Ruby, it fixed it. Hope this helps anyone with same issue.

Comment: Ruby versions is specified for a reason, probably because the same version is running in production environment and this helps avoid bugs caused by differences in environments. Changing Ruby version locally is NOT an answer to this problem, using a Ruby version manager (rbenv, rvm, asdf, ...) is.